# How to add ValueChangedListeners to Slider in Scaladin?

Tags: scala, vaadin

I don't know how to add a Listener to Slider in my application. I have HorizontalSlider. According to poor Scaladin documentation there should be some method like addListener, addValueChanged listener or something similar. Here's how it looks in Scaladin 1.0 example:

```
button.addListener(_ => doSomething())
layout.addLayoutClickListener(event => handleLayoutClick(event))
table.addItemClickListener(event => tableItemClicked(event))
```

I can't find anything like this. That's probably becaue I'm using Scaladin 2.0
The only thing I found is valueChangeListeners. It mixins ListenersTrait which has += operator. Therefore I would expect that something like this should work:

```
val revisionsNumberSlider = new HorizontalSlider {
    min = 1
    max = revisionsTodayLeft(true)
    resolution = 0
    value = 32
    width = (200 px)
    valueChangeListeners += (event => sliderChanged(event))
}

def sliderChanged(event: ValueChangeEvent) {
    revisionsNumberLabel.value = event.property.value
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. It compiles but sliderChanged method doesn't execute. I set a breakpoint inside it. Does anybody have any idea how to attach this function to slider? I'd be grateful for help.

Comment: Before anything else, you should check again that your listener is indeed never executed, by using some println statement. I know from experience that the debugger often fails to set break points inside scala closures.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I didn't set immediate = true.

```
val revisionsNumberSlider = new HorizontalSlider {
    min = 1
    max = revisionsTodayLeft(true)
    resolution = 0
    value = 32
    width = (200 px)
    valueChangeListeners += (event => sliderChanged(event))
    immediate = true
}
```